# Retreiving data from server from remote location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a server that is placed on another location (I have IP, username and password for connection). Could I use Asp.net C# web programming to make connection with that server and to retreive the data from server to web? Or I need to use another programming language? Please suggest any tutorial also.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understood now. So, basically you want to access your Remote Server for fetching the data only, maybe from SQL Server or something.

Yes you can surely use it. There are multiple ways of doing it :

1. Direct Access via SQL Server
2. Via Web Service. So, the Web Service which will reside on the Remote Server and will send you the data you need in either XML or JSON format.

Let me know if I did not understand it well.

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. I have a server that is placed on a remote location and in that server  I have database of some data being logged lets say values of temperature of rooms etc. I want to develope a website that access that servers data and to plot on the webpages.

Comment: In that case you will have to access the data using ADO.net, connecting to the server with necessary credentials.

Comment: Thanks Shekhar for your guide. I started with Visual Studio 2010, ASP.net MVC. I am now successfull to access data from server by adding a controller for database access and retereiving data from the server. Server is SQL.

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ViewExampleDatabase4-20121207182953;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the address of the remote database server in the connection string. For example, a connection to a remote MS SQL server with c# is established with

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;");
```

Where myServerAddress is the address of the remote server.

If you have a different Database, you can lookup the specific connection strings at 
http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Is there any complete tutorial that teachs how to make connection and access data from the database? I am beginner even with asp.net